# How to perform image classification in a dataset of images with heterogeneous sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a dataset of images with very different sizes (ranging from 100X100 pixels to 5000X1000 pixels) and aspect ratios. I want to use neural networks for dealing with this problem.

Is there any standard way to deal with datasets with this characteristics?

I know that a common practice is to resize the image and performing a center crop. But this throw away too much information of each image. I'm looking for solutions that preserves as much as possible of the original information.

Comment: Why not just resample them all to a common size and resolution?

Comment: It is not obvious to me how do this with images with very different aspect ratios without throwing away too much information of the images.

Comment: You don't have to throw anything away: just put a NoData border around those with extreme aspect ratios.

Comment: Do you have any example of code for doing this? It can be in Pytorch or Keras/tensorflow.

Comment: See [gis.se] for many, many code solutions.